# Problem with menu dhtml and css

Tags: dhtml, css

I found a vertical menu but I'm having some problems with it , because i have some incompatibility with ie 7, 8, 9 and also with safari, just it working for firefox.

Here I leave the website www.timetarget.com/newsite

please any help or comments will be help me .

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the position of .navmenu li:hover > ul to absolute.